# Why does my dash app justify = "center" not work?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, display

I am very new to Dash apps and I am writing a simple outline of how my app should look like.

```
my_simple_app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

my_simple_app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        # First row with title
        dbc.Row(html.H1("This part should center"), justify="center", align="center", className="h-50"),

        # Thematic break
        html.Hr(),

        # Second row
        dbc.Row(children=[
            # First column: dropdown
            dbc.Col(html.Span("It will be my dropdown"), width=3),
            # Second column: graph
            dbc.Col(html.Span("It will be my graph"), width=9)
        ])
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_simple_app.run_server()
```

However I am not able to display the header in center

[image: Webpage screenshot]

How can I get the header to display at the center of the page?

Answer (score 0):

First change your `dbc.Col` for a `html.Div` and give it a class name "header".

```
my_simple_app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        # First row with title
        html.Div(html.H1("This part should center"), className='header'),

        # Thematic break
        html.Hr(),

        # Second row
        dbc.Row(children=[
            # First column: dropdown
            dbc.Col(html.Span("It will be my dropdown"), width=3),
            # Second column: graph
            dbc.Col(html.Span("It will be my graph"), width=9)
        ])
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_simple_app.run_server()
```

Then create a folder called assets, and then a file called `header.css` and paste

```
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center}
```